# WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

i get this exception when starting the server :
`HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported`

my controller is :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        return "login";
    }

}
```

i really don't know what is the problem, since i am a very new to spring, could not even figure out what the problem is.

could somebody guide me to fix this

Comment: Have you checked if string `login` is referring correctly in `faces-navigation.xml` to the page you want to navigate ?

Comment: where is this file loacated faces-navigation.xml??

Comment: `faces-navigation.xml` is JSF stuff. There is no JSF tag but spring-mvc.

Comment: i am using spring and don't know why this confusing comment

Comment: Sorry, I misread the tags.

Comment: Yes, It is always good to explain when down voting the question or answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

change

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

(In your previous post I noticed that you have login-page=login)

Comment: tried this also did not work, i have added spring security after that only i get this problem

Comment: Post your web.xml and spring context xml

Answer (score 3):

RequestMapping is wrong.

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = `RequestMethod.POST`)

It will take only POST request and return 405 StatusCode any request not POST.

So, It should be

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = `RequestMethod.GET`)

Comment: decrease spring mvc's log level to debug or trace and let us know what's come out.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```