# web.servlet.PageNotFound ,Request method 'GET' not supported,Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I encounter a strange problem in my Spring MVC Controller.

I have four pages in my webapp folder

[image]

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/wodi/welcome",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcome(){
        return "redirect:/pages/webwelcome.html";
    }
}
```

Just now, it worked fine to find the page `http://localhost:8080/pages/webwelcome.html`, but now I have the error that the browser says:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Method Not Allowed, status=405).
Request method 'GET' not supported
```

I have no idea what I did that influence it.

I read [WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'GET' not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492927/warn-org-springframework-web-servlet-pagenotfound-request-method-get-not-s)

But this is not the same case as mine since I am using "GET" method.

Below is my Application.java to Boot the Spring app

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"hello","wodinow.weixin.jaskey"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandService commandService(){
        return CommandService.getInstance();
    }

}
```

Comment: Post configuration file web.xml and spring context.xml file code.

Comment: @JavaDev, I did not use that, I use Spring Boot and and Application.java to run the program.

Comment: On what request do you get the error : `http://localhost:8080/pages/webwelcome.html` or `http://localhost:8080//wodi/welcome` ? And as it looks like you are using eclipse, did you clean and then rebuild the project ?

Comment: @SergeBallesta Both the two URL have the same error,I tried clean the projects, but still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you put really weird thing in your config, the (embedded) container should be able to serve static content or JSP that are not under WEB-INF. The only use case where problem could happen would be if you map Spring `DispatcherServlet` to `/*` of forget to allow the serving of static resources.

You will find more references on the serving of static resources on my other post [Match for root url and serving of static resources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26325524/3545273).

But usually, in a controller you do not redirect to a HTML page, but give the name of a view and the view resolver finds the appropriate view.

Comment: "you map Spring DispatcherServlet to /* of forget to allow the serving of static resources." What will be the possible way for me to do that? And would you please show me a code sample for the last “solution that but give the name of a view and the view resolver finds the appropriate view”

Comment: Thank you! I find one of my requestmapping method(post method) is not declaring any "value", does it by default route to "/"?  And I add the a value="/some_path", and my solution is working! Thank you! If possible, I still hope to get one sample of your last suggestion: give the name of a view and the view resolver finds the appropriate view.

Answer (score 3):

In my case everything was ok. But i have a problem in a controller

that was my problem
    @RequestMapping( method = RequestMethod.GET)

y change for this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/usuario", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

and it works

Answer (score 1):

The ViewResolver registered in your application configuration is responsible for resolving pages  from a given URL.

Example: Config for resolving URLs like `/welcome` to corresponding JSP file `/pages/welcome.jsp`

```
<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="viewClass"
    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/pages/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

However, JSP pages are dynamic and need special handling. For static resources like plain html pages, it is sufficient to set up a static mapping for your pages folder.

```
<mvc:resources location="/pages/" mapping="/**" />
```

This would result in all resources in the folder /pages being mapped to URLs starting with "/". For example: `/pages/welcome.html` would be accessible by `http://yourdomain/welcome.html`

And if you want to set up a view resolver for one specific URL you can use a view-controller in the configuration:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/wodi/welcome" view-name="/pages/webwelcome.html"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

As you are using Spring Boot with @EnableAutoConfiguration you are already using the second method. [Here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L256-L260) you can see a code snippet from the AutoConfiguration implementation. It shows that a ResourceHandler is added to URL `/**` with some predefined [locations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L94-L98).

If you want custom URL mappings, I suggest you use one of the above mentioned methods in a plain Spring MVC configuration. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-enable) is the documentation for enabling Spring MVC config. You can decide yourself if you use xml or annotation based configuration.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I did not use any xml to config my app, I do indeed have a web.xml but I did not create that, maven creates it but I do not put anything new in it. Would you please post a complete code sample?

Comment: OP goes to the html page through a *redirect* (ok it is unusual) : the view resolver configuration should not be involved.

Comment: @SergeBallesta, would you please show me the way how it is usual to redirect to a html? I am new to Spring MVC, the existing project is built in Servlet before, and now I tried to refactor it into spring

Comment: @Jaskey, I edited my answer to give you some examples of possible Spring MVC configurations.

Comment: @Jaskey I updated my answer to elaborate on your configuration.

Comment: @Jeyp , I am new t Spring MVC, I find it hard to understand you, why the redirect failed? Shouldn't it be working fine? BTW,I do not have any xml file, so I don't konw how to test the solution you mention

Comment: @Jaskey - You don't have a xml file because you are using annotation based configuration with Spring Boot. Though using different syntax, both configuration types do the same thing. And with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` Spring Boot applies some default mappings. Can you post some startup logging of your application?

Comment: @Thank you ! I found that one of my method(Though it is a post method) is not declared a path, and now I do configure one, and my problem is solved. Would you please sow me an example of how I use configuration(not xml config) to  set up a view resolver to a page?

Comment: @Jeskey - Yes, you can find one example [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-view-controller). It's all in that Spring documentation chapter I linked in my answer. I really suggest you take a deeper look into Spring MVC's documentation. Spring Boot is cool, but it is best suited for zero configuration out-of-the-box functionality. If you want to customize your application, you have to understand Spring MVC in general either way.